# OPC-UaFx Sampling speed is extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

I need to read data in real time from a PLC S7 1500 using OPC-UA Client, at the rate of 50 hz.
So far I've tried a 3 different libraries. 2 of them I didn't find out how to use, and one preforms poorly in context of it's speed.

I've tried OPC Foundation's `OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua`, but couldn't figure all the parameters required to create a session. The only guide I found was some examples in their GitHub, which are pretty  complicated windows forms examples that I didn't manage to find out how to make use of: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard.

I've also tried QuickOPC by OPC Labs, but received an exception that looks to me like a certificate exception, and I could barely find anything about it on the internet.

The last worked best so far: `Opc.UaFx.Client` by Traeger.de (https://opcua.traeger.de/en/). I managed to read single data, multiple data, and read them in loops, but the amount of time it takes the application to preform each read of about 1kb of data is about 750ms, way above what I need. I've tried to work with subscriptions according to their guide in here: https://wiki.traeger.de/en/software/sdk/opc-ua/net/client.development.guide. But it sampled the subscribed nodes exactly every 1 second, even though I configured the `SamplingInterval` property exactly as they said in the guide. I figured that there are 2 more "interval" properties: `SamplingInterval` is for each item of my subscription, `PublishingInterval` is for the subscription itself, and there is also `CurrentPublishingInterval`, which is probably also for the subscription, but other than that, I also cannot change it and it always stays on 1000ms. I can only make it bigger when changing the `PublishingInterval`, but didn't find any way to make it smaller, which I guess is what I need.

Here is the code of what I've done in OPC UaFx:

```
private static Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using (var client = new OpcClient("opc.tcp://192.168.0.1:4840/"))
    {
        client.Connect();
        var node = client.BrowseNode(new OpcNodeId("\"communication data\".\"int array to send\"", 3));

        List<OpcNodeId> nodeList = new List<OpcNodeId>();
        OpcNodeId[] nodes;
        Browse(node, nodeList);
        Debug.WriteLine("done loading");
        nodes = nodeList.ToArray();
        stopwatch1.Start();

        SampleaAndMessureWithSubscription(client, nodes);

        Console.Read();
    };

}

private static void SampleaAndMessureWithSubscription(OpcClient client, OpcNodeId[] nodes)
{
    OpcSubscription subscription = client.SubscribeNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = new OpcMonitoredItem(nodes[i], OpcAttribute.Value);
        item.DataChangeReceived += HandleDataChanged;
        item.Tag = i;
        item.SamplingInterval = 20;                

        subscription.AddMonitoredItem(item);
    }
    subscription.PublishingInterval = 20;
    subscription.ApplyChanges();
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, either good OPC libraries and resources, or solutions for the issue with OPC UaFx.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re trying to read tags that are part of a UDT in the PLC then make sure you read the structured value from the Node at the root of the UDT, not the atomic values from each individual Node.

I doubt the client libraries are your problem here. The OPC UA server in the S7-1500 just isn’t very fast. I don’t know if it’s even capable of 50hz sampling. Check the revised publishing and sampling interval of your subscription and items after they have been created.

Comment: Thank you very much, all of your points seem to be exactly relevant. I'll try now to read the values from the root node.
And as for the the intervals: The SamplingInterval of the items, and the PublishingInterval of the subscription, are at 20 as I set them, and the CurrentPublishingInterval is 1000, like it's default

Comment: For some reason I have a memory that the fastest sampling interval the S7-1500 will support is either 100ms or 250ms, but I’m not certain. I’m still on holiday for another week so I can’t verify any of this until I’m back at my desk where I have an S7-1500 set up for testing. You might also do some testing with UaExpert, which should let you try to tweak the subscription and monitored item settings from the UI without having to write any code, so you can find the limits of the server.

Comment: I think that your memory is good, I found this source with details on the s7-1500. I see that there are different kinds of s7-1500 with different rates, but none of them goes faster than 50ms: 
https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109755846/what-are-the-system-limits-of-the-opc-ua-server-with-s7-1500-with-firmware-v2-0-x-and-v2-1-x-?dti=0&lc=en-LV
I will also try the testing you suggested with UaExpert tomorrow.
Thanks!

Comment: I think “Send interval” in that document is referring to Publishing Interval. If that’s the case, and you end up with a sampling interval faster than your subscription publishing interval, make sure that your monitored item queue size is large enough to accommodate all the possible changes that could occur between publishing intervals.

Comment: Regarding the exception you got from QuickOPC: You can report the issue on https://www.opclabs.com/forum/index and we will try to help.

Comment: Seems that the queue size is fine. It's defaultly set on 1000. Yet I've tried to play with it a little and it doesn't seem to have an effect.
I've also tried to use the ReadNodes method on an array of one single node, and got a result in only 6ms. This doesn't solve much since I need to sample around 400 nodes at once, but it makes me a little confused about the speed limit of the intervals. I still need to test the UaExpert, and reading from the root node.
@ZbynekZ Thanks for the offer, I'll keep working on my current route, since I'm already on it, but will definatly consider it for later.

Comment: I've downloaded the UaExpert, and tested it out: First I saw that my code's rate with ReadNodes was the same as in the UaExpert: about 750ms for reading 400 Nodes, and about 6ms for reading 1 node. Then I tried the Subscription, and here too I have the PublishingInterval which I changed from it's default (1000) to something else, and it always returned to 1000, exactly the same happend with the SamplingInterval of each item. I also saw in "Server Diagnostics View" > "Server Information" that there is a "MinSupportedSampleRate" parameter which looks unchangealbe.

Comment: “MinSupportedSampleRate” is usually informative, not something meant for configuration. It seems the performance of the server in this 1500 is limited even further than the previous document suggests. Is there anything else connected to it?

Comment: Nothing other than a switch between my computer and the PLC.
I also asked the owner of the PLC, and he said that it has no kind restrictions. Could it be that I'm not changing the intervals correctly? Or perhaps watching wrong results?... Could it be that there is yet some restriction in the server that the PLC owner missed?

Comment: I’m not sure about configuration, it’s been a while since I looked at it. If you can’t change the rates with UaExpert I would assume there is something with the server preventing it. UaExpert is generally easy to use and works. Does the log panel in UaExpert say anything about the server revising the rates after you try to change them? Maybe if the firmware version on the PLC is older it’s worth upgrading it to the most recent version.

Comment: Yes, after I change the PublishingInterval in the UaExpert, it returns a message "Revised values: ..., PublishingInterval = 1000". And after I change the SamplingInterval, it returns: "RevisedSamplingInterval=1000". (both of them I'm trying to change below 1000).
The firmware version of the device is V2.6. Not the most updated version. Do you know how essential it is to update? I don't have the tools to do it by myself, so it will be a little bit complicated.

Comment: This document suggests minimum sampling and publishing intervals are configurable in the server. You’ll need TIA portal to modify and download: https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/901/109737901/att_898965/v3/109737901_OPC_UA_Client_S7-1500_DOKU_V10_en.pdf

Comment: Yes, I see what you're talking about. I have just downloaded TIA Portal, though I don't have knowledge about it. We also want to move on with the work in the company. I'll see if I can find the right configuration and make it work, and if not I'll switch to S7netplus over of OPC-UA. Therefore I think we can close this question. @KevinHerron Thanks a lot for your help during your vication, it was very professional and helpful, very much appreciated.